# How to align an icon to always show next to the beginning of a line-CSS

Tags: html, css

I have a long name to be displayed at the title bar and next to the title i have a an icon that always needs to be on top or on the first line of the long title.
right now the icon gets pushed down with every line break.

eg: [image]

i'm trying to make the icon visible always at the top, next to where the top line begins.

html:

```
<div class="wrapper">
<span class="span_wrapper">sometextsometextsometext sometext sometext sometext sometextsometextsometext sometextsometextsometext sometextsometextsometext sometextsometextsometext
</span>
<span class="span_wrapper_icon"><span class="qx qx-left-arrow style="cursor: pointer;"></span></span></div>
```

css:

```
.wrapper {
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: #1361B0;
    height: 100%;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: #F5F5F5;
    font-weight: 300;
    font-family: Roboto;
    box-shadow: 0 9px 0 0 #F7F7F7, 0 -9px 0 0 #F7F7F7, 3px 0 8px -2px #607D8D, -3px 0 8px -4px #607D8D;
}

.span_wrapper{
    line-height: 30px;
    font-size: 20px;
    word-break: break-word;
}

.span_wrapper_icon {
    float: left;
    margin-right: 10px;
    position: relative;
    top: 2px;
}

.qx qx-left-arrow {
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 16px;
    width: 16px;
    padding: 5px;
}
```

any ideas?? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

put span_wrapper_icon above span_wrapper like this.

```
 <div class="wrapper">
   <span class="span_wrapper_icon"><span class="qx qx-left-arrow" 
    style="cursor: pointer;"></span></span>

   <span class="span_wrapper">sometextsometextsometext sometext sometext 
    sometext sometextsometextsometext sometextsometextsometext 
    sometextsometextsometext sometextsometextsometext
   </span>

 </div>
```

Hope this helps